# Pass $scope value from controller to a service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass a scope value to a service, what I'm doing now is declearing the service's  function in the controller and passing the scope value as a parameter to this function. Here is  the code

HTML code

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="dateDebut"   md-placeholder="Enter date"> </md-datepicker>
<md-datepicker ng-model="dateFin"  md-placeholder="Enter date" ></md-datepicker>
```

Controller code

```
app.controller('graphCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, graphDetails, $filter,$http) { 

  var self = this;

  self.dateDebut = $scope.dateDebut;
  self.dateFin = $scope.dateFin;

  var mettreAJour = graphDetails.mettreAJour(self.dateDebut, self.dateFin);

  $scope.labels = mettreAJour.labels;
  $scope.data = mettreAJour.data;
});
```

Service code

```
app.factory('graphDetails', function($filter, $http) {
  var labels = [];
  var data = [
    []
  ];

  return {
    mettreAJour: function(dateDebut, dateFin) {
      if (dateDebut && dateFin) {
        var dd = $filter('date')(dateDebut, 'yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss');
        var df = $filter('date')(dateFin, 'yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss');
        var dif = dateFin.getDate() - dateDebut.getDate();

        //do somthing with labels and data
        return {
          labels : labels,
          data : data
        };

      }
    }
  };
});
```

So I get as an error labels is not defined, and if I comment it I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
```

which means the code does not recognize `dateFin` nor `dateDebut`.

Is there another way to pass the scope to the service, or am I missing something in my current code?

Comment: I guess that your passing a reference of your object to your service, you can make a copy of your date objects with `angular.copy` and assign them to fields of your service and modify those fields in your service function.

Comment: Well, function `mettreAJour` returns `undefined` if either argument is undefined. No wonder the next line will throw `$scope.labels = mettreAJour.labels;`. You need to check before trying to access a property `$scope.labels = mettreAJour&&mettreAJour.labels;`

Comment: Yes, the mettreAJour function is definitely returning an undefined because  the parameters  are  undefined so the rest is undefined that's why the code dosen't recognize labels and data by the way. so my question was how to call these parameters knowing that they are scope values from controller to service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need to somehow reevalute values when either `dateDebut` or `dateFin` properties of scope change.

To achive this you can use `$watch` or `$watchGroup` methods of the scope. [Simplified Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vHJvzL6uz5159l6p2TEu?p=preview).

For example

```
app.controller('graphCtrl', function($scope, graphDetails) {

  // start watcher
  $scope.$watchGroup(['dateDebut', 'dateFin'], function(args) {
    var debut = args[0], fin = args[1];
    angular.extend($scope, graphDetails.mettreAJour(debut, fin))
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  $scope.$watchGroup works fine, now my function recognize my parameters dateDebut and  dateFin

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is because you are trying to return `labels` from `mettreAJour` but it is not aware of `labels` &  `data` .

Hope this below snippet will be useful.

```
app.factory('graphDetails', function($filter, $http) {
  var _graphDeatilsObject = {};
  _graphDeatilsObject.labels = [];
  _graphDeatilsObject.data = [
    []
  ];

  _graphDeatilsObject.mettreAJour = function(dateDebut, dateFin) {
    // Rest of the code
  }
  return _graphDeatilsObject;
});
```

Also take a look at [inline array annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)  which is required if you are minifying the code

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  but i still get the same error labels is not defined.